# Superscript last three characters in dynamic cell range

Tags: excel, vba, string, character, string-length

The code runs, but I would like to subscript the last three characters. Currently only superscripts the last characters.

Dynamic Date: Wednesday December 21, 2022(A)

```
 text = Row.Cells(1, 9).Value
    'Text = Row.Cells(1, 1)
    FileName = Row.Cells(1, 7)
    
    
        Set FileToOpen = Workbooks.Open(ClientPath & OldFileName, UpdateLinks:=0)
    
      Range("B4").ClearContents
      Range("B4") = text


   For i = 1 To Len(text)
    If i = Len(text) Then
    Range("b4").Characters(i, 2).Font.Superscript = True
  
    End If
  Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```vb
Text = Row.Cells(1, 9).Value
Filename = Row.Cells(1, 7).Value

Set FileToOpen = Workbooks.Open(ClientPath & OldFileName, UpdateLinks:=0)
With FileToOpen.Worksheets(1).Range("B4") 'or whatever sheet
    .ClearContents
    .Value = Text
    .Characters(Len(Text) - 2, 3).Font.Superscript = True
End With
```